# Joomla/Jomsocial include core.php

Tags: php, joomla, jomsocial

I want to use some functions of the Jomsocial core.php file which is discribed here:
http://documentation.jomsocial.com/wiki/Integrating_Your_Component

I want to get access to the user avatars. I build a php file, which shows me some user data that I get directly from the database and I want to show the avatar as well. The file is then shown in Jomsocial in a simple wrapper box, which loads my file.

I can't include the core.php file without getting an "Restricted Aceess" error on my page. 
I tried it to include the follwing way:

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
require_once( JPATH_ROOT .'/components/com_community/libraries/core.php' );
```

Even if I build a class.php file, include the stuff there an in my main.php file I include the class.php and create an instance of the class.php file I get the "Restricted Access" error on my main.php file.

So how can I use the core.php file and what I'm doing wrong? I now thats because of the security restrictions of Joomla or Jomsocial, but I actually don't know what I should do to get access to the file.

Comment: What happens is you use `define('_JEXEC', 1);` instead?

Comment: I got following error: defined() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given

Comment: Are you sure you used `define` and **not** `defined`? Note the `d` on the end

Comment: Oh you're right.It was a little bit too late for me ysterday. Thank you very much, that worked!!!+